# What is the Air Video Player in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming

What is the "Air Video Player", and how can I use it in my Android application? I think it is used for video streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Air video has two components

- Air Video Server: You install this on your own computer and you can add videos to be streamed to your idevice
- Air video client: This is the Iphone/Ipad app which helps you connect to your computer and stram the videos stored on your computer.

For Android check out this alternative

https://market.android.com/details?id=tv.wpn.biokoda.android.emitfree&hl=en

Comment: Thanks Sesha S for your reply but do you have any idea about how to use it into our application?

Comment: It is a stand alone app and I don't think you can embed it into your application. Perhaps you can look at VLC for streaming. Its quite powerful. http://www.engadget.com/2005/11/29/how-to-stream-almost-anything-using-vlc/ http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/

Comment: EMIT has been discontinued, so this answer is no longer useful.